# Interpreting Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given the question:

> $T: ℝ^n → ℝ^1$ such that $T(x) = x . y$ for $x$ $ϵ$ $ℝ^n$ where $y =
>  (y_{1}, y_{2}, \cdots, y_{n})^T$ is a fixed vector in $ℝ^n$.

How do i interpret this question to deduce whether it is a linear transformation? How do i also determine the standard matrix for the linear transformation?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of a linear transformation? I'm pretty sure it lists two properties. So you should verify whether this function satisfies those two properties. Same thing with the matrix -- start with the definition.

Comment: Hint: if $T: {\mathbb R^n}\to {\mathbb R^m}$ is linear, its matrix has shape $m\times n$ ($m$ rows and $n$ columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y$ is some fixed vector.  What you want to do is show that $T(x_0 +x_1) = (x_0+x_1) . y = x_0.y +x_1.y$

This should be quite easy.  To find the matrix representation you want to write $T(e_i)$ as a linear combination of the standard basis vectors.  This will yield a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Consider $T(ax_1+bx_2)$ against $aT(x_1)+bT(x_2)$.

The matrix representation is your typical standard dot product matrix.